# React useEffect cleanup for event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

In my React component, I have a event handling for beforeunload. I want to clean that up in my useEffect return. Is the below code the correct way of doing the same or is there any better way ?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(someKey).length > 0) {
        function callSvc(urls) {
        }
        callSvc(urls);
        
        const intV = setInterval(callSvc, interval, urls);
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {clearInterval(intV)});

        return () => {
            //window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", function() {clearInterval(intV)});
        }
    }
}, [someKey])
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(someKey).length > 0) {
        const intV = setInterval(callSvc, interval, urls);
        function clearTimer() {
            clearInterval(intV)
        }
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", clearTimer);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", clearTimer);
        }
    }
}, [someKey])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the below code the correct way of doing the same or is there any better way ?

There is a crucial problem with your code: Removing an event handler only works if you pass exactly the same function to `removeEventListener` that you passed to `addEventListener`. But as it stands you are passing two different functions. This is easy to solve buy storing the function in a variable and reference that variable in both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.

However, I question whether the `beforeunload` event handler is even necessary. When the page is closed any JS code stops running anyway. I think it's more important to stop the interval when the effect re-runs, otherwise you are starting a new interval whenever the effect runs again, resulting in multiple parallel intervals:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(someKey).length > 0) {
        function callSvc(urls) {
        }
        callSvc(urls);
        
        const intV = setInterval(callSvc, interval, urls);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(intV)
        }
    }
}, [someKey])
```

Comment: I added UPDATED CODE in my original question...Is that better ?

Comment: Yes, that will "work" but it still has the problem that a new timer will be created whenever the effect runs again... what's your intention behind using `beforeunload`?

Comment: My only intention behind using beforeunload is that the timer should be cleared whenever the browser page is closed. Also the dependency array i.e. someKey is going to change only on initial app load and not again....So that way the effect is not anticipated to be run multiple times...

Comment: OK. It would still make more sense to clear the timer in the cleanup function (i.e. the function returned from the effect). As I said, you don't have to worry about clearing the timer when the page is closed. That will happen automatically.

Comment: Oh k...So no need to have handler for beforeunload

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to `return` a function inside if-block, `useEffect()` will clean-up only if condition in if-statement is `true`, but when is no listener to add, there is no needed to clean-up on top level inside the `useEffect()` function.

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    let getThere = someBoolean
    if (getThere) {
      console.log("Listener Added.")
      return () => {
        console.log("Listener Removed. (Inside If statement)")
      }
    }
    return () => {
      console.log("No Listener to Remove.")
    }
  },[])
```

Then test switching the page by mount/unmount (I'm currently using `react-router-dom`) then watch the console.

if condition is `true`

```
Listener Added.
Listener Removed. (Inside If statement)
```

If condition is `false`

```
No Listener to Remove.
```

If the boolean is `true` the function will return the fucntion inside the if-block only, not flow into the outer return, except that the boolean is `false`, the code will go to return at outer level.

Comment: I added UPDATED CODE in my original question...Is that better ?